# Can dnsmasq return records in a specified order?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

My question is can I have dnsmasq return a number of records for one hostname in a specified order?

Perusing the man pages, I can't find anything seemingly relevant for (force) ordering the output.

in /etc/hosts.mywebserver.com I have defined the following entires.

```
    12.34.56.78    mywebserver.com
    34.56.78.90    mywebserver.com
```

And here is the problem when the DNS lookup is performed:

```
$ dig mywebserver.com
   mywebserver.com 0S IN A 12.34.56.78
   mywebserver.com 0S IN A 34.56.78.90

$ dig mywebserver.com
   mywebserver.com 0S IN A 34.56.78.90
   mywebserver.com 0S IN A 12.34.56.78
```

Both A records do come back, but they are not in the same order every time.

Anticipating someone answering might want to know this....I have configured a dnsmasq server on my ubuntu 16.04 server. I've disabled the NetworkManager version of dnsmasq and have installed mine via apt-get so that it's using /etc/dnsmasq.conf which is configured with addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.mywebserver.com. I have confirmed that this is working.

Comment: Any application that base itself on DNS order is wrong as the DNS deals with sets not lists, hence there is no specific order. The fact that each RRSET comes in a different ordering at each query is normal, expected and even a good thing, Why would you need a specific order? Also a TTL of `0` is over optimistic...

Comment: Thank you Patrick. We are using this to test something in a white box. We can deal with the sets. The TTL was real, but I was digging on the very machine running dnsmasq. So though unrealistic, irrelevant for the question at-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Only BIND Server can do this, as far as I know, BIND server has a specific setting that controls this 'rrset-order' in which this parameter can be set to 'fixed', 'random' and 'cyclic' as I recall.